# Can we use two Async-storage of react native in same project?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

firstly I had tried with one Async-storage data , it was working. The problem went with other Async-storage data that I gave on other form. It was not working. Can any one help me with this issue?

Data:-

```js
    StoreImageData = async () => {
        const Obj = "save"
        test.push(Obj)
        Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(test))
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('@Store', JSON.stringify(test))
          this.props.navigation.navigate('CarView');
          Alert.alert('Saved', 'Successful');
        } catch (e) {
          // saving error
        }
      }
```

Comment: yes you can use multiple async storage but you ave to provide different keys like suppose in one you have @ Store, for other you can have @ Department etc

Comment: You can store data using different @KEYS and retrieve it using those keys

e.g
`@Store`, `@userData`, `@Token`

Comment: @GauravRoy In the first storage I had given '@storage_Key' and for the new one I had given '@Store' . But it was not working.

Comment: can you share your code please wher eits not working and rest data

Comment: @GauravRoy The above code that I mentioned is the code. The part that I given for 'try' is not working.

Comment: how are you checking its not working?

Comment: I don't see any `@storage_Key` in the example code above either.. please give a minimal example that could cause what's 'not working' =].

Comment: @GauravRoy I had called StoreImageData() function to the button call.

Comment: so its not navigating to carView?

Comment: Yes, It is not navigating @GauravRoy